# Update old XCode Project with Size Classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, size-classes

I'm having a bit of a problem while updating my old iOS applications. I have seen other threads where developers suggest I just need to enable "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes". I did that and updated the storyboard, but the application still appears blown out on iPhone 6 while testing, along with the keyboard.

[image: Blown Out Image]
Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a correctly sized launch screen in your app bundle?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed everything.